# Illegal string offset 'locale' error in Laravel Voyager new user login

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I'm using Laravel Voyager for my web app.

When I added a new contributor user and tried to enter his dashboard. I got the "Illegal string offset 'locale'" error.

Error path: /home/turongro/public_html/vendor/tcg/voyager/src/Models/User.php

Error line:

```
public function getLocaleAttribute()
{
    return $this->settings['locale'];
}
```

Before getting this error, I changed `'locale' => 'ru'` in config/app.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [this issue reply](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3938#issuecomment-464424213), you can add `settings` field in casts inside `app/User.php`:

```php
protected $casts = [
  'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
  'settings' => 'json'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

php artisan config:cache

php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but here's my 2 cents.

After upgrading to Voyager 1.1, a settings field is added to the User table. In the settings field should be a locale field defined as JSON. It's missing in the upgrade guide unfortunately.

So, add to each user:

```
{"locale": "en"}
```